# I am using the latest kts build tool to learn Android hilt, but kapt seems to have some issues

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-hilt, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kapt

I am using the latest kts build tool to learn Android hilt, and I have introduced dependencies according to the official tutorial, but kapt seems to have some issues:

This is the root level build.gradle.kts of the project

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0-alpha04" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.0.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.20" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}
```

This is the app build.gradle.kts of the project

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    viewBinding {
        enable = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
}
// Allow references to generated code
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

This is an error while building the project

````
> Configure project :app
e: C:\Users\123\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build.gradle.kts:52:10: Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Action<KaptExtension> was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\123\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build.gradle.kts' line: 52

* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

  Line 52:     kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
                    ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Action<KaptExtension> was expected

1 error

* Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ```
````

Comment: [Please don't upload screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Have you followed the [Configure your build](https://developer.android.com/build#top-level) guide and added the Kotlin Android plugin to the top-level `build.gradle.kts` file?

Comment: Hello, I have re edited the issue and attached all the contents of the build.gradle.kts file. Can you help me take a look

Comment: good work, it's much more clear without the screenshot! Try removing `import org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt`

Comment: I  removing  ```import org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt```,  dependencies  ```kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")```  Will prompt ```Unresolved reference: kapt```

Comment: For the convenience of troubleshooting, I have added pictures after the problem

Comment: I have resolved this issue because my project is Java code, so there is no need to introduce kapt
Just put the
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
replace with
annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
You can use dependency injection now

Comment: hello, are you got the solution,  can you please help me?

Answer (score 10):

I have resolved this issue because my project is Java code, so there is no need to introduce kapt.

Write this:

```
annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
```

instead of

```
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
```

You can use dependency injection now.